# как svg сдвинуть(сделать анимацию) используя clipPath

Tags: javascript, css, svg, animate

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 47.5 47.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.5 47.5;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{clip-path:url(#path24_2_);}
    .st1{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    .st2{fill:#967B40;}
    .st3{fill:#66757F;}
    .st4{fill:#292F33;}
    .st5{clip-path:url(#path24_2_);fill:none;stroke:#6E48FD;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{clip-path:url(#path24_2_);fill:none;stroke:#12A6FF;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st7{clip-path:url(#path24_2_);fill:none;stroke:#3CFE0A;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st8{clip-path:url(#path24_2_);fill:none;stroke:#FEFF04;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st9{clip-path:url(#path24_2_);fill:none;stroke:#FFA010;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st10{clip-path:url(#path24_2_);fill:none;stroke:#FF0A0E;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st11{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);}
    .st12{clip-path:url(#SVGID_6_);}
</style>
<g id="layer2">
    <g>
        <clipPath id='slon'>
            <path stroke="#fff" fill="#D03E27" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="path24_3_" d="M44.7,20.2c-1.1-9.1-7.1-13-17.4-13c-0.5,0-1,0-1.4,0l0,0c-5.9-4.4-19.1-2.9-22,1.5
                c-4.1,6.1-1.5,27.9,0,30.8s5.9,4.4,7.4,2.9c1.5-1.5,0-1.5-1.5-4.4c-1.1-2.1-0.6-7.4,0.4-10.6c0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6
                c0.5,3.6,2.5,9.3,2.5,12.1c0,4.5,2.6,5.1,5.9,5.1s5.6-0.6,5.6-5c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9c1,0.1,1.9,0.1,3,0.1c0.6,0,1.3,0,1.8,0
                c0,0.3,0,0.5,0,0.8c0,4.5,2.6,5.1,5.9,5.1s5.9-0.6,5.9-5.1c0-2.3,1.5-5.8,2.5-8.8c0.3-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.5-1.4
                c0.1,1.6,0.3,3.4,0.3,5.3c0,0.8,0.5,1.3,1.3,1.3s1.3-0.5,1.3-1.3C46.6,28.8,45.7,23.7,44.7,20.2"/>
    </clipPath>
            <g id="lines" overflow="visible" clip-path="url(#slon)">
                <line class="st5" x1="17.2" y1="31.8" x2="-27.8" y2="-13.2"></line>
                <line class="st6" x1="18.6" y1="30.3" x2="-26.4" y2="-14.6"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="20" y1="28.9" x2="-24.9" y2="-16"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="21.4" y1="27.5" x2="-23.5" y2="-17.4"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="22.9" y1="26.1" x2="-22.1" y2="-18.9"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="24.3" y1="24.7" x2="-20.7" y2="-20.3"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="25.7" y1="23.3" x2="-19.3" y2="-21.7"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="27.1" y1="21.9" x2="-17.9" y2="-23.1"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="28.5" y1="20.5" x2="-16.5" y2="-24.5"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="29.9" y1="19.1" x2="-15.1" y2="-25.9"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="31.3" y1="17.6" x2="-13.6" y2="-27.3"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="32.7" y1="16.2" x2="-12.2" y2="-28.7"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="34" y1="14.8" x2="-10.9" y2="-30.1"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="35.4" y1="13.4" x2="-9.5" y2="-31.5"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="36.9" y1="12" x2="-8.1" y2="-33"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="38.3" y1="10.6" x2="-6.7" y2="-34.4"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="39.7" y1="9.2" x2="-5.3" y2="-35.8"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="41.1" y1="7.8" x2="-3.9" y2="-37.2"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="42.5" y1="6.4" x2="-2.5" y2="-38.6"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="43.9" y1="5" x2="-1" y2="-40"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="45.3" y1="3.5" x2="0.4" y2="-41.4"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="46.7" y1="2.1" x2="1.8" y2="-42.8"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="48.2" y1="0.7" x2="3.2" y2="-44.2"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="49.6" y1="-0.7" x2="4.6" y2="-45.7"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="-16.6" y1="65.5" x2="-61.5" y2="20.6"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="-15.2" y1="64.1" x2="-60.1" y2="19.1"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="-13.7" y1="62.7" x2="-58.7" y2="17.7"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="-12.3" y1="61.3" x2="-57.3" y2="16.3"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="-10.9" y1="59.9" x2="-55.9" y2="14.9"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="-9.5" y1="58.5" x2="-54.5" y2="13.5"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="-8.1" y1="57.1" x2="-53.1" y2="12.1"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="-6.7" y1="55.6" x2="-51.7" y2="10.7"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="-5.3" y1="54.2" x2="-50.2" y2="9.3"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="-3.9" y1="52.8" x2="-48.8" y2="7.9"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="-2.4" y1="51.4" x2="-47.4" y2="6.4"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="-1" y1="50" x2="-46" y2="5"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="0.3" y1="48.6" x2="-44.7" y2="3.6"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="1.7" y1="47.2" x2="-43.3" y2="2.2"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="3.1" y1="45.8" x2="-41.9" y2="0.8"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="4.5" y1="44.4" x2="-40.4" y2="-0.6"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="5.9" y1="42.9" x2="-39" y2="-2"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="7.3" y1="41.5" x2="-37.6" y2="-3.4"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="8.7" y1="40.1" x2="-36.2" y2="-4.8"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="10.1" y1="38.7" x2="-34.8" y2="-6.2"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="11.6" y1="37.3" x2="-33.4" y2="-7.7"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="13" y1="35.9" x2="-32" y2="-9.1"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="14.4" y1="34.5" x2="-30.6" y2="-10.5"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="15.8" y1="33.1" x2="-29.2" y2="-11.9"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="40.6" y1="55.1" x2="-4.4" y2="10.1"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="42" y1="53.7" x2="-2.9" y2="8.7"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="43.4" y1="52.2" x2="-1.5" y2="7.3"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="44.8" y1="50.8" x2="-0.1" y2="5.9"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="46.3" y1="49.4" x2="1.3" y2="4.5"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="47.7" y1="48" x2="2.7" y2="3"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="49.1" y1="46.6" x2="4.1" y2="1.7"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="50.5" y1="45.2" x2="5.5" y2="0.2"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="51.9" y1="43.8" x2="6.9" y2="-1.2"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="53.3" y1="42.4" x2="8.3" y2="-2.6"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="54.7" y1="41" x2="9.8" y2="-4"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="56.1" y1="39.5" x2="11.2" y2="-5.4"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="57.4" y1="38.1" x2="12.5" y2="-6.8"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="58.9" y1="36.7" x2="13.9" y2="-8.2"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="60.3" y1="35.3" x2="15.3" y2="-9.6"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="61.7" y1="33.9" x2="16.7" y2="-11.1"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="63.1" y1="32.5" x2="18.1" y2="-12.5"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="64.5" y1="31.1" x2="19.5" y2="-13.9"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="65.9" y1="29.7" x2="20.9" y2="-15.3"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="67.3" y1="28.3" x2="22.4" y2="-16.7"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="68.7" y1="26.9" x2="23.8" y2="-18.1"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="70.1" y1="25.4" x2="25.2" y2="-19.5"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="71.6" y1="24" x2="26.6" y2="-20.9"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="73" y1="22.6" x2="28" y2="-22.3"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="6.8" y1="88.8" x2="-38.1" y2="43.9"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="8.2" y1="87.4" x2="-36.7" y2="42.5"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="9.7" y1="86" x2="-35.3" y2="41.1"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="11.1" y1="84.6" x2="-33.9" y2="39.6"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="12.5" y1="83.2" x2="-32.5" y2="38.2"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="13.9" y1="81.8" x2="-31.1" y2="36.8"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="15.3" y1="80.4" x2="-29.7" y2="35.4"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="16.7" y1="79" x2="-28.2" y2="34"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="18.1" y1="77.5" x2="-26.8" y2="32.6"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="19.5" y1="76.1" x2="-25.4" y2="31.2"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="21" y1="74.7" x2="-24" y2="29.8"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="22.4" y1="73.3" x2="-22.6" y2="28.3"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="23.7" y1="71.9" x2="-21.3" y2="27"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="25.1" y1="70.5" x2="-19.9" y2="25.5"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="26.5" y1="69.1" x2="-18.5" y2="24.1"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="27.9" y1="67.7" x2="-17" y2="22.7"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="29.3" y1="66.3" x2="-15.6" y2="21.3"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="30.7" y1="64.8" x2="-14.2" y2="19.9"/>
                <line class="st5" x1="32.1" y1="63.4" x2="-12.8" y2="18.5"/>
                <line class="st6" x1="33.6" y1="62" x2="-11.4" y2="17.1"/>
                <line class="st7" x1="35" y1="60.6" x2="-10" y2="15.7"/>
                <line class="st8" x1="36.4" y1="59.2" x2="-8.6" y2="14.2"/>
                <line class="st9" x1="37.8" y1="57.8" x2="-7.2" y2="12.8"/>
                <line class="st10" x1="39.2" y1="56.4" x2="-5.8" y2="11.4"/>
            </g>

            <g>     
                    <!-- <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#lines" overflow="visible"> -->
                    </use>
            </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="g12" transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,0,47.5)">
        <g id="g14_2_">
                    <g id="g16_2_" class="st12">
                        <g id="g26_2_" transform="translate(20.3496,31.874)">
                            <path opacity="0.5" id="path28_2_" class="st3" d="M-0.4,0.8c0,0,3.7-5.5,0.6-10.5s-7.8-5-11-5c-2,0-1-2,0-2c1.4,0,8.4-1.2,12,6
                                C4.3-4.7-0.4,0.8-0.4,0.8"/>
                        </g>
                        <g id="g30_2_" transform="translate(9,22.8589)">
                            <path id="path32_2_" class="st4" d="M-0.4,0.8c0-0.8-0.7-1.5-1.5-1.5S-3.4,0-3.4,0.8s0.7,1.5,1.5,1.5S-0.4,1.6-0.4,0.8"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
  </body>
```

https://codepen.io/alex_din/pen/yoBdYX
по примеру выше когда пытаюсь создать анимацию lines (линии) сдвигаются но уже с маской, а нужно сместить саму "текстуру"

Answer (score 1):

```
#slon,#lines{
  transform: translateY(0px); 

}
#slon{
  animation: loading_1 3s infinite;
}

#lines{
  animation: loading_2 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes loading_1 {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% { 
      transform: translateY(9px); 
    },
 }

@keyframes loading_2 {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% { 
      transform: translateY(-9px); 
    },
 }
```

https://codepen.io/alex_din/pen/yoBdYX 
не знаю по чему маска смещалась вместе с заливкой, по этому я сместил маску назад и сделал анимацию.